# Convert java List to object using collection -Stream

Tags: java, list, object

From the method List> method() i get the output like this with 3 elements

```
[123456, 10, 03-JAN-16]
[956233, 20, 03-JAN-16]
[254656, 30, 03-JAN-16]
[455556, 40, 04-JAN-16]
[548566, 50, 03-JAN-16]
[215663, 60, 03-JAN-16]
```

I need to store the above result in a pojo class name 'ClassName' which has the following columns col1, col2 and col3, So I try to run the following code as

```
public void method() {
    try {
        List<List<String>> list = testDAO.methodName();
        List<ClassName> className= new ArrayList<ClassName>();
        for (Iterator<List<String>> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            List<String> list2 = (List<String>) iterator.next();
            int i = 0;
            ClassName className= new ClassName ();
            for (Iterator<String> iterator2 = list2.iterator(); iterator2.hasNext();) {
                String string = (String) iterator2.next();
                /* System.out.println(string); */
                if (i == 0)
                    className.setCol1(string);
                else if (i == 1)
                    className.setCol2(Long.parseLong(string));
                else if (i == 2)
                    className.setCol3(string);
                i++;

            }
            odhs.add(className);

            System.out.println(className);
            // System.out.println(className.col2());
            // System.out.println(className.col3());
        }
        // System.out.println("Total size: "+ odhs.size());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But i got the output as

```
com.project.model.ClassName@61af1510
com.project.model.ClassName@37af1f93
com.project.model.ClassName@778d82e9
com.project.model.ClassName@408e96d9
com.project.model.ClassName@59901c4d
com.project.model.ClassName@168cd36b
com.project.model.ClassName@d8d9199
com.project.model.ClassName@3901f6af
```

Please provide a solution to save the datas in the POJO class 'ClassName'

Comment: override `toString` in Odh  class

Comment: @Indrachith the output should contain only 6 entries.. rt?

Comment: No @Jobin it has more than 6 entries , i have just provided the sample output

Comment: okay. then is looks fine. you need to override toString() method..

Comment: Hi @Jobin i need to automatically bind the List result in my pojo class

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Odh` must override the [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) method.

Answer (score 0):

Override Odh's `toString` method.

Assuming the names of your parameters are `dist_id`,`pv` and `post_date` and all are of `String` types

```
@Override
public String toString(){
   return getClass().getSimpleName() + "[dist_id=" + dist_id + ", pv=" + pv + ", post_date=" + post_date + "]";
}
```

That would allow you to print

> Odh[dist_id=123456, pv=10, post_date=03-JAN-16]

Comment: @IndrachithR Could you please check, I have updated my answer. If that is not what you are looking for, then I'd suggest you to check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/29140403/3838328

All you need to do is override the toString method and make changes as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

On your `Odh` class you have to override toString method.

```
@Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Odh [firstAttribute=" + firstAttribute + ", secondAttribute=" + secondAttribute + "]";
    }
```